# Changing the scroll bar on React-Select

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, drop-down-menu, scrollbar

I'm trying to change the scroll bar styles to this react-select dropdown. I'm not sure how, I tried putting it in the custom styles but it doesn't seem to work. I want a certain scroll bar style for only this react select drop-down. Any suggestions?

```
  control: () => ({
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.1)',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 24,
    width: '220px',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }),
  singleValue: () => ({
    color: '#d7d7d7',
    gridArea: '1/1/2/3',
    marginLeft: '1px',
    marginRight: '1px',
    maxWidth: '100%',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    fontSize: '12px',
  }),
  indicatorSeparator: () => ({
    backgroundColor: '#d7d7d7',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    marginBottom: '8px',
    marginTop: '8px',
    width: '1px',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
  }),
  menu: () => ({
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: '#1A2129',
    borderRadius: '4px',
    boxShadow:
      '0 0 0 1px hsl(0deg 0% 0% / 10%), 0 4px 12px hsl(0deg 0% 0% / 10%)',
    marginBottom: '8px',
    marginTop: '8px',
    zIndex: 100,
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    width: '220px',
  }),
  menuPortal: (provided) => ({ ...provided, zIndex: 9999 }),
  MenuList: () => ({
    overflowY: 'auto',
    paddingBottom: '4px',
    paddingTop: '4px',
    zIndex: 100,
    position: 'relative',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
  }),
  option: () => ({
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    color: '#d7d7d7',
    cursor: 'default',
    display: 'block',
    fontSize: '12px',
    zIndex: 100,
    padding: '8px 12px',
    width: '',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.1)',
    },
  }),
  input: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    color: 'white',
  }),
};
```

and here is what it looks like

[image]

I want to add in these styles but not sure what to attach them to

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: transparent;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(90, 90, 90);
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 6.87501px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: transparent;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the component a class name as described [here](https://react-select.com/styles#using-classnames) and then use the class name to style the scrollbar. Something like

```
.dropdownClassName::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: transparent;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}
```